# ODOO13: Differences between QWEB report HTML and PDF

Tags: html, pdf, odoo, wkhtmltopdf, qweb

I have an issue that can't be resolved with the other answers about this topic.

I inherit an existing report (invoice) and change it and in HTML, the render works well but it is different in PDF render.

I have already try to set setting parameter like:

- web.base.url : 127.0.0.1:8069 or 0.0.0.0:8069 or whatever..
- web.base.url.freeze : True

But all that tips doesn't work. Some of lines I see in HTML are not displayed in PDF.

I work in Odoo13 and Ubuntu 18.04 Server and have wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt).

Have you got a magic solution for me ? I can update my question for more informations if you want.

Thank you so much.

Regards.

Images:

HTML: https://ibb.co/KDCHHmL

PDF: https://ibb.co/1KfY3ck

**UPDATE**:

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="address_custom" inherit_id="web.address_layout">
            <xpath expr="//t[@t-set='colclass']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="t-value">('col-md-5' if report_type == 'html' else 'col-5')</attribute>
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr="//div[@class='address row']" position="replace">
                <style type="text/css">
                    .certif{
                        font-size: 16px;
                        margin-bottom: 3cm;
                    }

                    .tva{
                        font-size: 14px;
                    }

                    div[name="address"]{
                        margin-top: 20px;
                        font-size: 20px;
                    }

                    #informations, h6{
                        font-size: 15px
                    }

                    .invoice_name{
                        margin-top: 30px;
                    }

                    table, th, td {
                        border: 1.5px solid black;
                    }

                    th, td {
                        padding: 0 10px;
                        text-align: center;
                    }

                    .full-width{
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                    .td50{
                        width: 50px;
                    }

                    .td75{
                        width: 100px;
                    }

                    .td150{
                        width: 200px;
                    }

                    .td350{
                        width: 400px;
                    }

                    .o_standard_footer{
                        margin-top: 20px;
                    }

                    .clearfix{
                        margin-top: 1200px;
                    }

                    td{
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }
                </style>
                <div class="address row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <p class="certif">CERTIFICATION MASE N° RA 2017-200 du 05/07/2017</p>
                        <p class="tva">TVA sur encaissements</p>
                    </div>
                    <div name="address" class="colclass">
                        <t t-raw="address"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>


        <template id="report_custom" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']" position="replace">
                <h6 class="invoice_name">FACTURE N° <span t-if="o.name != '/'" t-field="o.name"/></h6>

                <div id="informations" class="row ml4 mb32">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><strong>Code Client</strong></th>
                                <th><strong>Date de Facture</strong></th>
                                <th><strong>Page N°</strong></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p class="m-0" t-field="o.partner_id.ref"/></td>
                                <td><p class="m-0" t-field="o.invoice_date"/></td>
                                <td><span class="page"/> / <span class="topage"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <t t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="line">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <span t-attf-class="{{ 'font-weight-bold' if not line.display_type else '' }}" t-field="line.name"/>
                        </div>
                        <div t-if="not line.display_type" class="col-md-2">
                            <span t-field="line.price_subtotal"/>
                        </div>
                        <div t-if="not line.display_type" class="col-md-1">
                            <t t-foreach="line.tax_ids" t-as="tax">
                                <span t-field="tax.description"/>
                            </t>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div id="total" class="row">
                        <p class="text-sm-left">"Art.D.441-5 - Le montant de l'indemnité forfaitaire pour frais de
                            recouvrement prévue au douzième alinéa du I de l'article L.441-6 est fixé à 40 euros."</p>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <table class="full-width">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="td50">
                                            <p>C20</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="td150">
                                            <span t-field="o.amount_untaxed"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="td150">
                                            <span t-field="o.amount_untaxed"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <t t-foreach="o.amount_by_group" t-as="amount_by_group">
                                            <t t-if="len(o.line_ids.filtered(lambda line: line.tax_line_id)) == 1 and o.amount_untaxed == amount_by_group[2]">
                                                <td class="td75"><span t-esc="amount_by_group[0]"/></td>
                                                <td class="td150">
                                                    <span t-esc="amount_by_group[3]" />
                                                </td>
                                            </t>
                                        </t>
                                        <td class="td350">
                                            <table class="full-width">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td class="text-right"><span t-field="o.amount_untaxed"/></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <t t-foreach="o.amount_by_group" t-as="amount_by_group">
                                                            <t t-if="len(o.line_ids.filtered(lambda line: line.tax_line_id)) == 1 and o.amount_untaxed == amount_by_group[2]">
                                                                <td class="text-right">
                                                                    <span t-esc="amount_by_group[3]" />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </t>
                                                        </t>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><br/></td>
                                                        <td><br/></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td class="text-right"><span t-field="o.amount_total"/></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Maybe you should share the QWeb Code which isn't shown in the pdf?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Updated question.

Comment: Hm it's difficult to understand, but the first thing i've seen is replacing the whole `<div class="page">`. You should atleast begin your custom code with such a `div` again (right before `h6`)

Comment: Oh damn! I didn't have seen before!! I'll investigate this way. Thank you so much!

Comment: I added a div with page as class but that seems have no effect... So I want to inherit the base invoice qweb template and replace some content but nothing works well for me.. Maybe I don't do it correctly